# JAXB Unmarshalling derived types

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Based on the following program, it prints out what we expect it to correctly.
Is it possible for such a program to unmarshall correctly if the classes ClassA and ClassB used
the same XmlRootElement name?  For example, if they were both defined as "typeA"...?  Would it be
possible to do something like that with JAXB?

```java
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.Date;

public class JaxbABCTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        final JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(ABC.class);
        final Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
        final Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();

        ABC class1 = new ClassA();
        ABC class2 = new ClassB();

        final ByteArrayOutputStream baosA = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        final ByteArrayOutputStream baosB = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        // Marshall to XML
        marshaller.marshal(class1, baosA);
        marshaller.marshal(class2, baosB);

        String xmlA = baosA.toString(Charset.defaultCharset().name());
        String xmlB = baosB.toString(Charset.defaultCharset().name());

        System.out.println(xmlA);
        System.out.println(xmlB);

        // Now attempt the reverse.
        Object unmarshalA = unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StringReader(xmlA));
        Object unmarshalB = unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StringReader(xmlB));

        System.out.println(unmarshalA.getClass());
        System.out.println(unmarshalB.getClass());
    }
}

@XmlTransient
@XmlSeeAlso({
    ClassA.class,
    ClassB.class
})
abstract class ABC {
    private int a;

    @XmlAttribute
    public int getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public void setA(int a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
}

@XmlRootElement(name = "typeA")
class ClassA extends ABC {
    private String b;
    private Date c;

    @XmlAttribute
    public String getB() {
        return b;
    }

    public void setB(String b) {
        this.b = b;
    }

    @XmlAttribute
    public Date getC() {
        return c;
    }

    public void setC(Date c) {
        this.c = c;
    }
}

@XmlRootElement(name = "typeB")
class ClassB extends ABC {
    private String b;
    private Date c;
    private boolean d;
    private float e;

    @XmlAttribute
    public String getB() {
        return b;
    }

    public void setB(String b) {
        this.b = b;
    }

    @XmlAttribute
    public Date getC() {
        return c;
    }

    public void setC(Date c) {
        this.c = c;
    }

    @XmlAttribute
    public boolean isD() {
        return d;
    }

    public void setD(boolean d) {
        this.d = d;
    }

    @XmlAttribute
    public float getE() {
        return e;
    }

    public void setE(float e) {
        this.e = e;
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean? can you give an xml example?

Answer (score 1):

For straightforward JAXB unmarshalling, (root) one element name refers to an element with a specific structure which is mapped to one certain Java class.

You can, of course, define a class containing the union of the fields of A and B - as long as fields occuring in both classes match. You'll have to have some attribute that lets you decide which of the two "subclasses" it really is. (This is similar in spirit to using an XPath expression that includes a test for the presence (or even value) of an attribute or element.)

You may also pursue a more elaborate approach leaving this element unmarshalled after reading the XML, investigate the DOM tree and create a JAXBContext according to what has been detected. This will let you use the same element name with Java types exactly matching the XML content. Of course, an unambiguous criterion must be available, and youÄll have to write the code for analysing based on te raw DOM tree data.

Comment: Thanks for this.  The more "elaborate" approach that you've suggested is appealing to me, though I'll need to investigate how to hook/override the unmarshalling code correctly as it's currently handled by RestEasy.

Comment: This depends how you define the XML element types, XML Schema or annotations in Java classes. See https://jaxb.java.net/tutorial/section_2_2_16_1-Elements-With-Any-Type.html#Elements%20With%20Any%20Type for a brief intro.